# Swift Generics and Protocol issues for multi-level-deep generics/protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift3

I'm planning on making a flash-card app for Chicago kids that can take in many kinds of questions as long as they can conform to the same protocol. Ideally there will be many different games ranging in difficulty and the view will be able to consume all the games because all the games will conform to the same protocols. I'm wanting each turn to have the ability to take in a totally different kind of struct as long as it is equatable.

I feel like i'm getting close but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the game to take in any data without getting errors... I feel like i'm getting close but can't get past this speed bump.

I keep getting errors such as "TurnDefinable can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associate type requirements"

```
protocol GameDefinable {
    associatedtype TurnType: TurnDefinable
    var turns: [TurnType] { get }
}

class Game<T: TurnDefinable>: GameDefinable {
    var turns: [T]

    init(turns: [T]) {
        self.turns = turns
    }
}

class Turn<A: AnswerDefinable>: TurnDefinable {
    var question: String
    var correctAnswer: A
    var answers: [A]

    init(question: String, answers: [A], correctAnswer: A) {
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correctAnswer = correctAnswer
    }
}

protocol TurnDefinable {
    associatedtype AnswerType
    /// Localized string to ask the user a question they must answer
    var question: String { get }
    /// Array of possible answers
    var answers: [AnswerType] { get }
    /// Correct answer per turn
    var correctAnswer: AnswerType { get }
}

protocol AnswerDefinable: Equatable {
    // Will have more stuff here like localized formatted string, etc
}

// Just created this test pretending our answers will be Ints
struct ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct: AnswerDefinable {
    static func == (lhs: ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct, rhs: ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.testInteger == rhs.testInteger
    }

    // Just created this to get the equatable
    var testInteger = 0
}


struct ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct2: AnswerDefinable {
    var string: String
    static func == (lhs: ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct2, rhs: ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct2) -> Bool {
        return lhs.string == rhs.string
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much so appreciated...

EDIT: I am much closer now, I just need to figure out how do be able to use two turns with different answer types

```
let turnExample1 = Turn<ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct>(question: "Which is the lonliest number?", answers: [ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct(testInteger: 1), ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct(testInteger: 2), ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct(testInteger: 3)], correctAnswer: ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct(testInteger: 1))
let turnExample2 = Turn<ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct2>(question: "You say goodbye, and i say ...", answers: [ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct2(string: "hello"), ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct2(string: "goodbye")], correctAnswer: ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct2(string: "hello"))

let testGame = Game(turns: [turnExample1, turnExample2])
```

I'm so close! Thanks to all the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

I've got an idea but I'm not sure about it.

Two instantiation of a Generics class are only the same type if all of them use the same type, eg Integer.
Having an associatedType in a protocol may mean one instantiation is not usable the same as another instantiation.

Using TurnDefinable means two instantiations can have different types, and the compiler maybe doesn't like to have differing types in an array(unusable).
Unusable cause you can't all turns treat the same, call the same functions, access the same variables.
A function with a different function signature is not the same function anymore.

How would you write the following if the compiler would just ignore it?

```
for turn in turns {
    turn.answers.first!.X // ???
}
```

You could use an empty Answer protocol and type switch on it. Maybe it helps.

```
protocol Answer {}

for turn in turns {
    for answer in turn.answers {
        switch answer {
        case let type1 = answer as AnswerType1:
            break //
        case let type2 = answer as AnswerType2:
            break
        default:
            fatalError("Answer type unknown \(type(of: Answer))")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd hope that given that they all have the same protocol that the compiler would let me access the same functionality on all of them... Do you think there's a way to do this [Array of Protocol Objects]? They'd all essentially have the same logic. (correct answer, array of answers) but with different structs within.

Comment: [Array of Protocol objects] usually works incase its the same Protocol. But you tried to store differing protocols inside the array, which does not work.

Just store the same protocol in there(no associatedtype) which can be equatable and so on.. .
And if you want to access the specific underlying type of the Answer you can typecast, type switch on the answer.

Maybe there’s a better more pretty solution, I don’t know.

Comment: You could also make the Answer as an Enum, with cases like **case textAnswer(_ answer: TextAnswer)** etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an array of type `TurnDefinable` because it is a protocol with an associatedtype as you've seen.

You need to adjust your `GameDefinable` protocol to have it's own associated type which you can use as the type for the array:

```
protocol GameDefinable {
    associatedtype TurnType: TurnDefinable
    var turns: [TurnType] { get }
}
```

Then, you can add a generic parameter to your `Game` class which will be used as the associatedtype for the `GameDefinable` protocol (you could also skip the generic parameter and declare the arrays with a specific type like `Turn<ExampleOfAnAnswerStruct>` if you want to restrict your Game to a certain type):

```
class Game<T: TurnDefinable>: GameDefinable {
    var turns: [T]

    init(turns: [T]) {
        self.turns = turns
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! Gets me so close! I'm just trying to figure out how I can use different kinds of turns in a single game, now. I've updated the question, now!

Comment: I see, that actually makes it considerably more complicated.  There might be some way to do it with type erasure magic but I'm not sure.

Comment: definitely. I know there are other hard-coded ways to get around but I'm trying to make this as generic as possible so I can diversify the questions asked within a single game... Examples: "What street is directly east of Wells?" (LaSalle) and "How far west is Ashland Ave?" (1600 W). I'd rather have individual structs that are equatable rather than init'ing a struct has convenience inits from other classes to conform itself to an equatable string.

Comment: The only way I can think to do it is to remove all the associated types and make `Turn` use an array of `AnswerDefinable` and `Game` use an array of `TurnDefinable`.  This works but you lose the constraint that a turn's answers must all be the same type and you have to use something other than `Equatable` to compare answers.

Comment: The problem is one can't use an array of TurnDefinable without the error "Protocol 'TurnDefinable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"

Comment: Right, that's why you would have to remove the associatedtype from `TurnDefinable` and change the `AnswerType`s to `AnswerDefinable`